# What is the time complexity of the following procedure

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

What is the time complexity of the following procedure

```pascal
for  ← /2 to  do
     ← 2
    while ( < ) do
         ←  + /2
         ←  ∗ 2
    end while
end for
```

Comment: What do you think it is, and why? How often is the outer loop executed? How often is the inner loop iterated in one iteration of the outer loop. It's quite easy to determine because the iteration count of the inner loop only depends on `n` but not on `i`. And `k` seems to be unused and therefore irrelevant.

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. It's ok to ask homework questions but you should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) first. This is not a site for doing your homework for you ...

Comment: @MarkDickinson no I didnt miss a line, and youre right because I think k seems to be unused.

Comment: It's `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite inner loop as `for` and we can see timings:

```
for (int i = n / 2; i < n; ++i)     # outer:     n / 2 limes
  for (int j = 2; j < n; j *= 2) {  # inner:     log(n, 2) times
    k += n / 2;                     # combined: (n / 2) * log(n, 2) times

    ...
  }
```

As you can see,

```
T(n) = (n / 2) * log(n, 2)
```

Time complexity is

```
O(T(n)) = O((n / 2) * log(n, 2)) = 
        = O(n * log(n) / log(2)) =
        = O(n * log(n))
```

Finally, we have time complexity

```
O(T(n)) = O(n * log(n))
```